# Get All record from my database for the month by Percentage

Tags: c#

I am building a report for my application using VS2010.
My DB has two tables:Users and clinical_data.The Users table has a Column named:Gender,
PatientRegistrationNo and the Clinical_data table contains Column:RegistrationNo.
For each Registered user that exit in the Users table and has Clinical_data store for
him or her, I want my Query to show:
Total Count of Male and Female, % of Male and Female for the Current Date:
This is my query but is not working for me:

```
    select COUNT(gender )  From Bio_Data
where  DateCreated = ADDDATE(GETDATE());
```

Comment: percentage = (subset count / total count) * 100

Comment: Use case statement to get count of males and females

Comment: Seems like your db has 3 tables. how does Bio_Data fit into this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following query will help you to get your result

```
SELECT ( Sum(CASE 
               WHEN Gender = 'm' THEN 1.0 
               ELSE 0 
             END) / Count(*) ) * 100 AS male_percent, 
       ( Sum(CASE 
               WHEN Gender = 'f' THEN 1.0 
               ELSE 0 
             END) / Count(*) ) * 100 AS female_percent, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN Gender = 'm' THEN 1.0 
             ELSE 0 
           END) / Sum(CASE 
                        WHEN Gender = 'f' THEN 1.0 
                        ELSE 0 
                      END)           AS ratio, 
       Sum(1)                        AS total_Male_Female 
FROM   Users 
       INNER JOIN Clinical_data 
         ON Users.RegistrationNo = Clinical_data.RegistrationNo
```